# what is に's role in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, usage

> その巨大{きょだい}な学園{がくえん}は都会{とかい}のど真{ま}ん中{なか}の一等地{いっとうち}**に**聳{そび}えたっていた

I can understand the meaning of this sentence but I can't comprehend what「に」is meaning in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The immediate question

This に is the locative に indicating where something is happening.

> どこ​**[に]{●}**​立【た】ちますか。
>     Where `[LOC]` stand `[question mark]`.
>     → Where [do you] stand?
>     ここ​**[に]{●}**​立【た】ちます。
>     Here `[LOC]` stand.
>     → [I] stand here.

In your sample sentence, the に tells us where the action is taking place -- specifically, where その巨大【きょだい】な学園【がくえん】 ("that giant school") is 聳【そび】え立【た】っている ("standing really tall → towering").

#### Deeper analysis

I suspect you're having trouble breaking down the grammar of the sentence.  Let's do that now.

> その巨大{きょだい}な学園{がくえん}は都会{とかい}のど真{ま}ん中{なか}の一等地{いっとうち}**に**聳{そび}えたっていた

1) What are we talking about here?  Look for the topic particle は:

> その巨大{きょだい}な学園{がくえん}​**[は]{●}**

So we're talking about a 学園{がくえん}.  The words before the 学園{がくえん} modify that noun and tell us more about it: the 学園{がくえん} is, more specifically, その ("that") 巨大【きょだい】 ("giant") 学園{がくえん} ("school").

2) What are we saying about the 学園{がくえん}?  What is it doing?  What is the main verb of our sentence?  In Japanese, that's generally at the end:

> 聳【そび】えたっていた

This is a verb phrase with three verbs: 聳【そび】える ("to be really tall"), 立【た】つ ("to stand"), and いた, the past tense of いる ("to be"), used to form progressive constructions.

Putting these back together, we get "being really tall" + "standing" + "was" → "was standing really tall" → "was towering".

3) Where is the action happening?  We can usually tell by looking for the locative particle に:

> 都会{とかい}のど真{ま}ん中{なか}の一等地{いっとうち}**[に]{●}**

So the action is happening in the location marked by the に: in this case, in an 一等地【いっとうち】, literally a "first-class [piece of] land", i.e. a "prime location".  The words before the 一等地【いっとうち】 tell us more about it, so we know that it is 都会{とかい}のど真{ま}ん中{なか}の, or "right in the middle of the city".

---

Please comment if the above does not answer your question.